# how to refer to strings from input dialog?

Tags: java, string, joptionpane

I need to prompt the user to enter their full name and once they do I need two separate messages to show them `your first name is` and `your last name is`. I have everything but what I need to code for the `firstName` and `lastName` string. I feel like it has something to do with `indexOf`? but I can't get it to work correctly.

```
public class project2b {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String fullName;

        firstName = 
        lastName =  
        fullName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your full name?");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your first name is " + 
        firstName);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your last name is " + 
        lastName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`InputDialog` will only return a single `String`. You need to parse it. `String` has a handy `split()` method that will do the parsing for you.

Assuming the user enters their first and last name separated by a space, this will work.

```
String fullName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your full name?");

String[] names = fullName.split(" ");
String firstname = names[0];
String lastName = names[1];
```

My answer does not cover validation. You would normally validate the user's input before using it, but I believe it to be out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] names = fullName.split ("\\s");
firstName = names[0];
lastName = names[1];
```